# Spring boot automatically restarts when doing file IO from intelliJ

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, intellij-idea

I have a very strange issue where my spring application will end all threads and restart when I programmatically save a file to the resources folder. What's odd is that the problem seems to disappear if I package to war and deploy on a tomcat server, yet when I run it from IntelliJ the problem is there. What's more is that I am wanting this file write to happen right after Spring starts, leading to this infinite loop of the application starting and restarting. I check in the resources folder within the build folder and see that the file is getting save each time spring starts, but the application seems to crash right afterwards.

Here is the code I'm using to write the file:

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(
        this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("processes/").getPath() + "/filename.xml"
);
fos.write(processXML);
fos.close();
```

Comment: Did you try saving the file to somewhere else also? In any case, that directory won't be available (by default, unless you re-create it) once you package and execute the Spring Boot app.

Comment: You would lose those files on redeploy - if those are temporary files one could write to the temp-dir. Persistent data (that should survive a redeploy) usually goes under '/var/...`.

Comment: Good to know, but temp files will be okay in this situation

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That is not strange at all.

You are having in your classpath dependency:

```
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools
```

You are writing to the location that is being scanned for changes by spring boot reload component - which results in infinite loop as you said.

Set in your application.properties:

```
spring.devtools.restart.enabled = false
```

More on that here:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-devtools.html
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-hotswapping.html

Answer (score 0):

Just add two things first devtools dependency in pom.xml and property in yml file.

```
#for not restarting the server every time
spring.devtools.restart.enabled:  false

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
```